# eforms border does not appear in edge

Tags: forms, textfield

Oddly, the border is shown in Chrome and Acrobat, but not in Edge (don't know about Firefox). Did I do anything wrong?

```
\documentclass[11pt,a4paper]{scrartcl}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{ifthen}
\usepackage{eforms}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\newcounter{linecounter}
\newcommand{\linie}[2]{
    \foreach \n in {1,...,#1}
{   \ifthenelse{\n=1}{\definePath{\ABC}{#2}}{\definePath{\ABC}{}}
    \stepcounter{linecounter}
    \textField[
    \Ff\FfDoNotSpellCheck
    \Ff\FfDoNotScroll
    \BC{0 0 0}
    \textColor{0 0 0}
    \textSize{12}
    \V{\ABC}
    \S{U}
    ]
    {\thelinecounter}{\textwidth}{1.5\baselineskip}

\vspace*{.3cm}
}
}

\begin{document}
\linie{3}{Wenn...}
\end{document}
```

Comment: the code looks ok. You could try to make the line (much) thicker (with `\W 5`, but probably edge simply can't handle the `\S{U}` setting.

Comment: Already tried to thicken the line. Did not work. So you're probably right. Sadly, with Firefox it does'n work at all...